# Split window into half on vertical screen

Tags: multiple-monitors

Running Ubuntu 20.04. I have two monitors currently. One main one horizontal(2560x1440), and one to the right that is vertical(1920x1080). What is the best way to automate opening one full-size chrome window on the main monitor and one chrome window on the top half of the vertical monitor?